# PDF JavaScript calculations

Tags: javascript, pdf

Until this morning I did not know it was possible to have JavaScript in a PDF, but a work colleague needs help.

She has 5 textfields defined. They are labelled **£TRAVEL**, **£SUBSISTENCE ACCOMODATION**, **£TELEPHONES**, **£MISCELLANEOUS** and **£Less cash advance**

4 of these fields will take number input which will be summed up and the 5th field input subtracted from the sum of the first four.

Then there is a 6th field which will display the result.

I am trying the following code:

```
var travel = this.getField("£TRAVEL");
var accom = this.getField("£SUBSISTENCE ACCOMODATION");
var teleph = this.getField("£TELEPHONES");
var misc = this.getField("MISCELLANEOUS");
var less = this.getField("£Less cash advance");

(travel + accom + teleph + misc) - less;
```

Am I on the right track and if I am, how do I assign the calculation to a 6th textfield below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like:

```
var travel = this.getField("£TRAVEL").value;
var accom = this.getField("£SUBSISTENCE ACCOMODATION").value;
var teleph = this.getField("£TELEPHONES").value;
var misc = this.getField("MISCELLANEOUS").value;
var less = this.getField("£Less cash advance").value;

this.getField("name_of_6th_field").value = (travel + accom + teleph + misc) - less;
```